# Pyenv: activate.sh command not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyenv

When opening a vscode terminal when the python extension is loaded, it tries to execute this:

```
source /Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/activate.sh
```

Which triggers this error:

```
pyenv: activate.sh command not found

The `activate.sh` command exists in these Python versions:
    2.7.4
```

And then bluntly closes the terminal. Is there an issue with my pyenv installation here?

Context:

- `which python` > `/Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/python`
- `python --verison` > `Python 3.7.4`
- VSCode: Version: 1.41.1
- OS: macOS 10.14.6
- `pyenv versions`:

  ```
    system
    2.7.14
    3.4.3
    3.5.4
    3.6.4
    3.6.6
    3.6.9
  * 3.7.4 (set by /Users/victor/.pyenv/version)
  ```
- Problem arises:

  - only in VSCode's integrated terminal (not in other shells or terminals)
  - only when the Python Extension loads the default Python interpreter (`/Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/python`) => does not occur when it is configured to load a virtualenv's Python interpreter
  - on all Python version I configure with `pyenv global`
  - except if I select a specific Python interpreter as default (`~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python`) in which case the terminal is opened with `pyenv shell 3.7.4` (see @Brett Canon's comment)

Comment: Is the shell you are using in VS Code the same you are comparing to externally? And what is `"python.pythonPath"` set to? If it's set to `/Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/python` then I would undo that and point at a specific version of Python as you should be controlling the Python version in the extension and not externally from it (the extension makes assumptions based on the version selected).

Comment: Yes I've configured it to be the same (zsh 5.1 + oh-my-zsh)

Comment: @BrettCannon I've updated my question, you pointed to a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

The Python extension doesn't execute anything on your behalf for pyenv. You/pyenv probably added a command to your shell's configuration file which is trying to run that source command and it turns out to not work with 3.7.4 set as your active pyenv version.

Comment: If that's the case then why does it only happens with vscode's integrated terminal?

Comment: I should also add, and I'll update my question accordingly, that this pb does not happen when pthe python extension is configured to use a virtualenv's python interpreter. But it happens for any version of python that I can set with "pyenv global"

Comment: Best I can suggest is open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.